# What's a good way to output matplotlib graphs on a PHP website?

Tags: php, python, matplotlib

I have a python script that can output a plot using matplotlib and command line inputs.

What i'm doing right now is making the script print the location/filename of the generated plot image and then when PHP sees it, it outputs an img tag to display it.

The python script deletes images that are older than 20 minutes when it runs. It seems like too much of a workaround, and i'm wondering if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your python script so it outputs an image (image/jpeg) instead of saving it to a file. Then use the  tag as normal, but pointing directly to the python script. Your php wouldn't call the python script at all, It would just include it as the src of the image.

Comment: That sounds like something I'm trying to do. What's a good way to feed inputs to the python script like that? I don't have a web framework installed.

Comment: You'd have to pass the data in the url, probably as a query string. I'm mostly familiar with mod_python, but there are ways to get at the query string with out using a framework.

Comment: As far as I know, without mod_python, when the browser read the python script file, it reads in plaintext and python never gets executed.

Comment: You can run python as cgi, but I won't be able to help much there. If you put you python script in a .cgi file, that is usually already setup to be handled correctly. You just have to have #!/your/path/to/python on the first line. Look into the cgitb  library documentation on the python site.